# How to pass the selected value of dropdown to an independent componenet using redux and reactnative?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

this my first component contain a dropdown

********** SelectDropDown.js*************

```
export default function SelectDropDown() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(null);
  data=["option1","option2","option3","option4",]

  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    console.log(data[e]);
    setVal(e);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ModalDropdown
        options={data}
        multipleSelect={false}
        defaultValue="Selectionner OF"
        style={styles.DropDown}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

---

i want to pass the selected value of the dropdown to Screen1 (ButtonsGroupe,Detaille) and screen2

*****************Screen1.js***************************

```
export default function Screen1() {
  return (
    <>
      <SelectDropDown />
      <ButtonsGroupe />
      <Detaille />
      
    </>
  );
}
```

*****************Screen2.js***************************

```
export default function Screen2() {
  return (
    <>
       <ButtonsProd />
       <Production />
       <DataProd />
       <Details />      
    </>
  );
}
```

---

i'am puted Screen1 and Screen 2 in StackNavigator to navigate between them

*************Nav.js********************

```
export default function Nav() {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Screen1" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </>
  );
}
```

---

and finally i'am called those component to app.js

*****************app.js***************

```
export default function App() {
 
  return (
    <>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar animated={true} hidden={true} />
          <HeaderBarNavigation />
          <Nav />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

please can someone help me to resolve this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of what you want to do is that you are trying to pass some data between screens that are not relative (neither child or parent).

Since you are using react-navigation, you are allowed to pass params when you are calling the screen.

I would suggest somthing like that :

```
    export default function SelectDropDown({navigation}) {
      const [val, setVal] = useState(null);
      data=["option1","option2","option3","option4",]
    
      const handleSelect = (e) => {
        console.log(data[e]);
        setVal(e);
      };

  useEffect(() => {
    if(val){
      navigation.navigate('Screen1', {superCoolParam : val})
    }
  }, [val]);
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ModalDropdown
            options={data}
            multipleSelect={false}
            defaultValue="Selectionner OF"
            style={styles.DropDown}
            onSelect={handleSelect}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

And then :

```
export default function Screen1({route}) {

  useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Catching params => ', route.params.superCoolParams)
  }, [route]);

  return (
    <>
      <SelectOF />
      <ButtonsGroupe />
      <Detaille />
      
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: sorry but i have a mistake in Screen 1, SelectOF will be replaced with SelectDropDown,
in this case the navigation will not work with my needs ,
i am tried to pass the data of dropdown with api context but not working also